# Outlook force closes because Avast finds malware

Tags: ms-office, anti-virus

Almost as soon as I open Outlook 2011, Avast pops up with it's shield warning:

[image]

That's [MSIL:GenMalicious-ALS [Trj]](http://www.avast.com/en-gb/virus-update-history#2014m09).

Outlook has then "encountered an error and needs to close"; too quickly for me to determine which message this is an attachment to.

I can delete the file from `~/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/Outlook Temp`, but it just downloads and happens again.

I'm still pretty new to Mac - so I'm not as sure how to deal with this as on Windows. What can I do to stop Outlook re-downloading it, or how can I safely stop Avast quitting Outlook?

Comment: Interestingly I just started getting the same error! I am considering putting in a path exclusion in Avast for that temp folder to see if that bypasses it temporarily but concerned if this is a true infection.

Comment: One of my end users just had this issue.  Removing it 3 times and relaunching Outlook 3-4 times resolved it for them.  I wasn't there to witness it but I did look at the logs and confirm that it happened.  I'm not adding this as answer since it seems a little too flaky of a solution, might help someone though.

Comment: @MrRabbit Hmm, I've tried it a few more in vain hope, but no luck so far.

Comment: Just to add to this, my user called back with it reoccurring.  The "kcal-whatever" file that it is flagging and quarantining seems to be a normal temporary file that appears (then disappears) whenever Outlook is connecting to the email server.  In the end I went with the assumption that it's a false positive hit and just added ~/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/Outlook Temp to the list of exclusions in Avast.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same thing. Most likely false positive